# Why does my MacBook Pro keep freezing?

Tags: macbook-pro

Once in a while my MacBook Pro 10.8.2 freezes for a couple of seconds, this is really annoying. Mouse gets frozen, I can't move it, and screen gets frozen. These are the last messages from the kernel, how to solve this?

```
Sandbox: sandboxd(38380) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38410) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38429) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38463) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38495) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38513) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38550) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38581) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
Sandbox: sandboxd(38599) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
CODE SIGNING: cs_invalid_page(0x1000): p=38605[GoogleSoftwareUp] clearing CS_VALID
Sandbox: sandboxd(38632) deny mach-lookup com.apple.coresymbolicationd
```

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't recover and you have to force it to reboot, then you most likely have a hardware issue. Usually the hard drive.